# Flutter circular progress bar will not allow me to add image in the middle of it instead of the percentage for progress, I'm using this Radial Gauge

Tags: android, ios, flutter, progress-bar

I am using flutter to build a mobile application with a rewards collection option. What I am trying to do is put an image of the product in the middle of the progress bar with a counter under it to show the number of collected items (in this example in the image we have coffee).

I've tried using the "sleek_circular_slider" package and the "Radial Gauge widget" but with no luck. I checked all the modification options here https://pub.dev/documentation/sleek_circular_slider/latest/ and there's no option to add an image here even.

This is what it currently looks like with the percentage bar
[image]

```
final slider = SleekCircularSlider(
  appearance: CircularSliderAppearance(
    customWidths: CustomSliderWidths(progressBarWidth: 10)),
  min: 10,
  max: 28,
  initialValue: 14,
);
```

And this is how I'm trying to have it look like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the innerWidget to any widget.

```
final slider = SleekCircularSlider(
  appearance: CircularSliderAppearance(
    customWidths: CustomSliderWidths(progressBarWidth: 10)),
  min: 10,
  max: 28,
  initialValue: 14,
  innerWidget: (double value) => Align(Text('${value.round()}/5')),
);
```

This is a screenshot from my app which uses several SleekCircularSlider widgets nested inside each other, and then I have a Text widget at the very center:

[image]

Comment: can I see what the code is like for that please

Comment: I added an example to my response, but as I said, you can pass any widget that you like. Cheers!